# How to organize variable administration/views for the same model in a django project?

Tags: django, oop, data-modeling

I have a problem but I don't know the best way to organize the django project. I have the same model for two types of tournaments (it is only an example)

- Tournament (type knockout or league)
- Match

If the tournament is a knockout I must create all the matchs for the first round but if it is a league I must create all matchs for all the league.

The admin page for the knockout should be a knockout tree and the league a table with the results and the classification

How can I organize the code?

Currently I have a knockout application and a league application and, when the user select "admin" it redirect to an application depending of the tournament type.

Another problem is: I need to run some process when a user create or change the tournament, when the user add or remove teams etc, but the same problem: when the type is knockout I need run X proccess but if it is league run Y proccess.

I need a scalable solution for new types of tournaments but I don't know what is the best arquitecture/organization.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can subclass model classes, but I'd probably keep things simple and stupid:

- create a model for tournament. One of its fields would determine what kind of tournament it is
- create a model for match

Tournament class would contain the code to create its associated matches.

I wouldn't worry about scalability at this time too much. Solve the problem you have *now*. When you have 6+ types of tournaments and the tournament class gets convoluted you'll also have better idea how to split up the logic.

Comment: Finally I've created a service layer. There is a KnockoutService and a LeagueService then a function get_tournament_service(). This function return the service depending on the tournament type and the classes uses it without know the implementation. This is a very common java pattern but I don't know if there is a better way in python